# value of a hash map element not printing properly

Tags: c++, hashmap

I insert a pair (key,value) to my hashmap but it seems like it doesn't have the value when trying to print it

The thing is i don't know why i can't print the second element in the following code.

Let's see some code :

.h

```
typedef hash_map<const string, string, strptrhash, strptrequal> StringHashMap;  
StringHashMap m_memberNameMap; 
typedef pair <const string,string> string_pair;
```

.cpp

```
void Powerdomain::addMemberName(const string& name){  

if (m_memberNameMap[name]==""){
    m_memberNameMap.insert(string_pair(name,name));
    StringHashMap::iterator it = m_memberNameMap.begin();
    cout << it->first << endl;
    cout << it->second << endl;
    cout << m_memberNameMap["MD1"] << endl;
}
```

with name="MD1" this outputs :

```
MD1  
*blank*  
*blank*
```

EDIT

concerning the answer of Alan :

```
ModuleType * moduletype4=new ModuleType("type4");
ModuleType * value = moduleTypeMap["type4"];

if (value==NULL) {
   ModuleType& value2=*moduleTypeMap["type4"];
   value2=*moduletype4;
   cout << "correctly inserted" << endl;
}
cout << moduleTypeMap["type4"]->getName() << endl;
```

This doesn't work. I Might be confused now !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does `m_memberNameMap[name]` do in the `if` condition? If the key `name` doesn't exist in the map, it creates a *new* slot with that key, and value equal to empty string.

That is, the expression `m_memberNameMap[name]` invokes `operator[]` which inserts an item equal to `string_pair(name, "")` to the map if the key `name` doesn't exist,

The solution is to use `find` as:

```
if (m_memberNameMap.find(name) == m_memberNameMap.end())
{
    m_memberNameMap.insert(string_pair(name,name));
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Instead of `insert` function, you can also use :

```
   m_memberNameMap[name] = name; //simpler, cute!
```

After all, `operator[]` creates a new slot if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: yup i was misunderstanding what [] did. Thank you ;) Is there a way to get an exception if there is already a certain key in the map and the insert will have no effect ? thus i can do a try catch instead of the if ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud: You can get exception if you want to, but for that you've to write your own function inside which you've to use `find` again. So why go this way? Why not use `if` instead where you want to use your function. Also, try-catch is not better than using `if`. Avoid it!

Comment: @Nawaz So you are saying that is commonly better to do something like //if (not here) {add it} else {throw exception} then a try catch ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud: Why do you want to throw exception? You can change the return type of function `addMemberName`  from `void` to `bool`, and return `false` if the value is not inserted, and `true` if the value is inserted!

Comment: hm i'd like to throw an exception because i want to have a report file that consists of the different insertion problem. My program reads files. let's say file A has a member called X and file B has a member called X. My reader will attempt to add X two times in the map and this is something i want to report in my output log file. Are exception a bad way to do that ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud: If you can do that by changing the return type from `void` to `bool`, and returning `true/false`, then yes exception is a bad approach here, because you can avoid it. Also note that, exception should be avoided as much as possible, because its relatively expensive compared to returning `true/false`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several misconceptions here. First, using the `operator[]` in the map, will actually **insert** a new (empty) element with the key `name`. The semantics of this operator are that if you *access* an element inside the map, it has to be there, so if it doesn't exist, it is created. Then, the `insert` operation is defined to **not** to add the element if it already exists, so this is your problem.

You should be using find first:

```
if (m_memberNameMap.find(name) == m_memberNameMap.end()) // don't exist
{
   // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: yup i was misunderstanding what [] did. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use `operator []`, you can just save its result to ensure only one lookup occurs:

```
string & value = m_memberNameMap[name];
if (value.empty()) {
   value = name;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: if my map is like typedef hash_map<const string, Other*, strptrhash, strptrequal> OtherHashMap myMap; then myMap[] is a ref or the object or an adress of Other ?

Comment: It's a reference to an Other*, ie to a value inside the map.

Comment: Try ModuleType * & value = moduleTypeMap["type4"];